# Why is the latest stable version of Newtonsoft showing in Nuget Package Manager as 12.0.3 in one project and as 9.0.1 in another?

Tags: nuget, visual-studio-2019

In my class library, Manage Nuget Packages shows the latest stable version of Newtonsoft as 12.0.3.  In another application that references the class library, Manage Nuget Packages shows the latest stable version of Newtonsoft as 9.0.1

What would explain that difference, and how is it fixed in Visual Studio 2019?  When I try to compile the application, it fails with the error that the class library's version of Newtonsoft is newer.

EDIT: I think I've found the reason: in the top right corner of the window the package source for the application was not `nuget.org` but `Visual Studio Offline Sources`.

Comment: To help other community members search and handle similar issues, I have added an answer here. And it is also for you. You can check it. Anyway, have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why is the latest stable version of Newtonsoft showing in Nuget
> Package Manager as 12.0.3 in one project and as 9.0.1 in another?

When you install a nuget package, you should select the right [nuget package source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#package-sources).

As it shows that, `Visual Studio Offline Sources` is your local nuget caches. It is required that you download the corresponding nuget version and then exist in this data source. So it depends on you and not all versions of the package are fully displayed.

`nuget.org` is the ultimate destination for developers releasing nuget packages. You can find every version of the package here. So you should check this link.

[image]

Check and enable that link.

Then, open **Nuget Package Manager UI** and choose `nuget.org` and you can find it.

[image]

Comment: One strange thing that I've noticed is that even after correcting the package source, the Version drop-down on the package manager window doesn't refreshes at once. So I selected another nuget package and came back to `Newtonsoft.Json` package.  After that it started showing all latest versions available for update.